# Restoring MacBook hard drive when using Bootcamp and Time Machine

Tags: hard-drive, macbook, boot-camp, time-machine

I recently lost the hard drive in my 2008 MacBook Pro which had OSX 10.5 and Vista (dual boot). A friend helped me replace the hard drive and install the original OSX and I took the opportunity to upgrade from Vista to Windows 7. I didn't use Time Machine correctly to restore the OSX partition and now I would like to try again.

**Can I "wipe" my OSX partition and reinstall OSX using Time Machine without reinstalling Windows 7 on the other partition?**  I can reinstall Windows 7 from scratch but I don't want to do it if I don't have to.

Some background info:

2008 MacBook Pro 17" (10/2008) with Mac OSX 10.5 Leopard

Before: 320M Hitachi drive with **200Gb for OSX** partition and **100Gb for Vista**

After: 320M Western Digital drive with **100Gb for OSX** partition and **200Gb for Windows 7**

The drive crashed on 1/2010. This laptop spent 99% of it's time on the desktop. When I carried it to clients it was turned off (because Vista's "sleep mode" is really "coma mode" i.e. you have to reboot it if it goes to sleep under Vista). I am not impressed with the hard drive.

thanks in advance!

Comment: by 100M and 200M, do you instead mean 100GB and 200GB??? I'd love to see an OSX or Vista install in 100 megabytes!

Answer (score 1):

After you boot off the osx cd, you should be able to go into disk utility and only format the partition that osx is installed on. After this you should able to proceed with the installation, and restore your TM backup to this partition.

Comment: Will Bootcamp be able to "find" my Windows partition? Remember, the size of the Windows partition and the operating system on that partition have changed (100Mb Vista -> 200Mb Win7)?